# How can I tell ld to link to a local symbol in a shared object?

Tags: symbols, gcc, dynamic-linking

Symbols in shared objects can be either local or global.  This is controlled by a flag in the symbol table. If the symbol is local, ld won't resolve to it.

Reverse engineering can often be aided by doing this, by linking a shared object and referencing its symbols (e.g. `printf("%p", main_arena)`.  Since all the information is there, and its only a flag telling ld to ignore this, it should be possible to tell ld to resolve a local symbol as well.  How can I do this?

Note that a simple patch of the flag isn't enough:

```
objcopy --globalize-symbol=main_arena libc-2.30.so libc-2.30.global_symbols.so
```

even though the symbol is now listed as global, `ld` still can't find it, because all global symbols must be before any local (see https://github.com/lief-project/LIEF/issues/112 ) and perhaps for other issues (see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6527014/making-a-local-symbol-global ).  It might be possible to rebuild the entire symbol table, but this will introduce other changes that we don't want.  What we want is simply to tell `ld` "Please break the rules and resolve local symbols as well, just like gdb does."

Comment: Why not change `ld`'s source, build and do whatever?

Comment: By `ld` you mean `ld` (from Binutils, or `lld.ld` from Clang) or you mean `ld.so`?

Comment: @0xC0000022L `ld.so`